# Is there a word for publishing old news online?

Tags: terminology

I wonder if there's a term or a word that describes the publishing of old/historic news from the archive to online in whatever way - for example, typing an article manually.

Comment: Do you mean re-reporting _current_ news (from newspapers to online). Or do you mean publishing historic news (from archive) to online ?

Comment: The latter, please!

Comment: Then I suggest an edit : ) 'Old' news could mean 'an hour old' in our modern fast-paced society.

Comment: More specific than "uploading" or "putting online"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, I would probably use the word digitize. ex. The manuscripts are being digitized for preservation.  Or there are many places to find digitized newspapers.
Or online archiving.

Comment: Digitize covers the process of creating an digital copy from an original but it doesn't convey the meaning that the digital copy will be "published" online.

Comment: True. Possibly online archiving then.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I think that's it. `Digitize` or `Online Archiving` will do.